# Jasmine Angular testing if input would show required message

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to check whether after I submit, login form without username / password, I will receive an error message below the certain field, and i done a simple test scenario for that:

```
it('password input should display required message', async() => {
    
    component.validateForm.controls['password'].setValue('');
    const submitBtn = el.querySelector("[data-test='submit']") as HTMLElement;
    const control = el.querySelector("[data-test='password-control']") as HTMLElement;

    submitBtn.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(control.innerText).toContain('Please input your Password!');
});
```

html code:

```
<form nz-form [formGroup]="validateForm" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" data-test="form">
  <nz-form-item >
    <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please input your username!" data-test="username-control">
      <nz-input-group nzPrefixIcon="user" >
        <input type="text" nz-input formControlName="username" placeholder="Username"/>
      </nz-input-group>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please input your Password!" data-test="password-control">
      <nz-input-group nzPrefixIcon="lock">
        <input type="password" nz-input formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </nz-input-group>
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
  <div nz-row class="login-form-margin">
    <div nz-col [nzSpan]="12">
      <label nz-checkbox formControlName="remember">
        <span>Remember me</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div nz-col [nzSpan]="12">
      <a class="login-form-forgot">Forgot password</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button nz-button class="login-form-button login-form-margin" [nzType]="'primary'" data-test="submit">Log in</button>
  Or
  <a>register now!</a>
</form>
```

and when I tried this in browser by running in dev tools after submiting form without typing anything in password input
`document.querySelector("[data-test='password-control']").includes('Please input your Password!')` it returns `true`, I also tried adding to code above tick(1000), before expect statement to make sure, there is enough time to make it appear before the check, but it hasn't changed anything, the test result is negative with message `Expected '' to contain 'Please input your Password!'.`.

Will be happy with any suggestions to solve that issue :)

Comment: Could you share the HTML associated with the test?

Comment: yes, just pasted it in

Comment: It will be difficult to tell what exactly is going on with (what I assume to be) all the custom elements and directives. Here are a couple thoughts though: Are you using `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` or `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` in your testbed? These schemas result in shallow rendering, and nested elements won't actually render unless explicitly declared in the testbed. I'd recommend [debugging tests in the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/test-debugging). If you focus the test (`fit`), and follow the instructions (set breakpoints), you can see what is actually getting rendered in the UI.